# How to get data attribute value on afterChange vue-slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slick.js

I'm working using vue-slick and google analytics. I display data using vue-slick, and will send the data that I will manipulate to google analytics. I store the data in the `data-items` attribute (object). So the scenario is when the slide changes, the data that will be sent to Google Analytics is the data on the slide that is being displayed. The problem is I don't know how to access the `data-items` attribute that I have created. does anyone know how i can access it?

```
<vue-slick
  v-if="mainBanner.length > 0"
  id="slider-main-banner"
  ref="slick"
  :options="slickOptions"
  @afterChange="handleAfterChange"
>
  <a v-for="banner in mainBanner" :key="banner.sys.id" :href="banner.fields.url" :data-items='{"name" : banner.fields.image.fields.file.fileName, "img" : banner.fields.image.fields.file.url }'>
    <img :src="banner.fields.image.fields.file.url" :alt="banner.fields.image.fields.file.fileName" class="img-fluid">
  </a>
</vue-slick>
```

```
methods: {
  handleAfterChange (event, slick, currentSlide) {
    console.log('handleAfterChange', event, slick, currentSlide)
    console.log(this.$el.getAttribute('data-items'))
  }
}
```

Comment: "Reading the values of these attributes out in JavaScript is also very simple. You could use getAttribute() with their full HTML name to read them, but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringMap you can read out via a dataset property."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes